# C# adding labels to tablelayuot

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I tried to add labels and rows to tablelayout. When i used adding to listview like that:

```
ListViewItem ite = new ListViewItem(tag);
ite.Text = (tag + " " + description + war);
listView2.Items.Add(ite.Text);
```

it work,but when i try another it doesn't work. Why? There aren't any errors or exceptions.

```
 foreach (DataElement elementy in sq)
 {                       
       for (int k = 0; k == row_number; k = k + 1)
        {
        tag = elementy.Tag.ToString();
        description = elementy.VR.Tag.GetDictionaryEntry().Description;



       // ListViewItem ite = new ListViewItem(tag);
        //ite.Text = (tag + " " + description + war);
        //listView2.Items.Add(ite.Text);

            tableLayoutPanel1.GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
            Label et_tag = new Label();
            et_tag.AutoSize= true;
            et_tag.Text = tag;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(et_tag, 0, k);
            Label op = new Label();
            op.AutoSize = true;
            op.Text = description;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(op, 1, k);

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop won't run unless `row_number` is 0. Otherwise, it will fail its condition immediately after K is initialized and, as a consequence, do nothing. Your loop almost certainly isn't running. If row_number actually *is* 0, your loop will run exactly once for every item in your outer `foreach` loop.

What condition do you want the loop to run on? Do you mean `k < row_number` instead? Do you just want to do this for a single k where `k == row_number`, in which case you should simply assign row_number to k and get rid of the loop entirely? I don't know where row_number comes from, so I don't know what this code wants to do.

Comment: row number is a number of tags for each element in sequence. Each element has two tags describing it. I want to show these tags in tablelayout.

Comment: You want a loop bound of k < row_number (since you're starting your count at zero), but there's another problem here. Nothing involving elementy involves k. You're just going to print the same tag row_number times, because you haven't made the program look anywhere else for tag data.

Comment: Oh, that's right -> 'k< row_number' or 'k== row_number-1'. But i don't know what you mean about another problem. How can i repair it?

Comment: I repaired my program. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: It's not just the off-by-one. That == evaluates as true only for the last desired iteration of the loop; the < evaluates as true for all iterations. But a for loop stops as soon as it sees the first false, so the loop will, once again, never run at all (or run only once) with the k == row_number - 1. It's not an "end condition" for the loop, it's the "loop condition"- the condition under which the loop runs.

Comment: As for the second problem- which it sounds like you fixed!- what do you need to do to tell elementY which tag you're interested in? Right now, it looks like elementY only has one tag, which it will repeat again and again, row_number times.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're initializing row_number, but perhaps it should be something like:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= row_number; k = k + 1)
```

Comment: I repaired my program. Thanks a lot:)